# Change color depending on remaining time

Tags: javascript, colors, countdown

I were wondering if there was a simple way to change the color on a countdown-timer (I want the color on the timer to change into red once there is less than 12 hours left)

```
    CountDownTimer('09/09/2013 23:59', 'countdown');
    CountDownTimer('09/11/2013 15:30', 'countdown2');


function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class=exp>Utgått!</span>';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + ' Dager ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + ' Timer   ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' Minutter  ';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

This is the code I'm using. 
In advance, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following line:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.color = days === 0 && hours < 12 ? 'red' : '';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/btMGs/5/).

Which will set the `color` of the containing element to `'red'` if there are zero days *and* less than twelve hours left, or set it to nothing (passing an empty string) if there are one, or more, days or twelve, or more, hours left.

Though I would suggest caching the element you're using *once* and then using *that*, rather than re-querying the DOM every time:

```
var cachedEl = document.getElementById(id);

/* all the other stuff... */

cachedEl.innerHTML = days + ' Dager ';
cachedEl.innerHTML += hours + ' Timer   ';
cachedEl.innerHTML += minutes + ' Minutter  ';
cachedEl.innerHTML += seconds + ' Seconds.  ';
cachedEl.style.color = days === 0 && hours < 12 ? 'red' : '';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/btMGs/4/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick respond :) i tried that, but it makes alle the timers with less than 12hrs red, also, timers with 3 days and 5hrs etc

Comment: You're very welcome; hopefully the answer is of some use to you! =)

Comment: Again, thank you. But it didn't work, I got 5 timers, and 4 out of 5 turns red with that script :s

Comment: Yeah, I just changed the ternary operator, adding a second condition to check. Should work now? Basically, we're *now* checking that there are `0` days (if you have weeks, months and/or years in your real page you'll need to check for those being zero too) as well as `< 12` hours left.

Comment: Oh, figured it out
cachedEl.style.color = days ==0 & hours < 12 ? 'red' : 'black';
Thank you mate :) Have a good eve!

Comment: damn, you're quick:D quicker than me atleast. again, thank you mate, been struggling with this for a few hours^^

Comment: No problem at all; and you are, of course, very welcome indeed! Best of luck with whatever you're doing with it next. =)